# Property animation inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I want to create an animation inside `RecyclerView` with `PropertyAnimation`. I need to make invisible each of my rows and also to moving from down to up.

Inside the adapter, I have created a routine which is run inside `OnBindViewHolder`

```
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        viewToAnimate.Animate()
                   .TranslationYBy(500)
                   .TranslationY(0)
                   .AlphaBy(0)
                   .Alpha(1)
                   .SetDuration(2000)
                   .SetStartDelay(5);

        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

My rows doesnt move and doesnt become from invisible to visible. They are totally static. I know that it's xamarin code, but I tag also as java cause it is simulately code for me.

Comment: You should use an `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` otherwise you 
will cause memory leaks and weird behaviors -  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator

Comment: In setItemAnimator i need to create an xml with my animation values. Right? I don't mind if this is the way i just wonder if i can do it using propery animation inside recyclervie wadapter

Comment: `ItemAnimator` doesn't require xml you can use a propertyAnimator it just handles the view's recycling.

Comment: Oh thank you sir, i didn't knew that! Can you write me a small example? Also which it will be the object inside property animator? RecyclerView?

Comment: It will be the view in the viewHolder. Here are some samples https://hackmd.io/s/r1IEQ-jAl

Comment: Do you want to add animation for RecyclerView sliding or delete one item ?

Comment: I need to create animation like link below https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213   But using objectanimator or viewpropertyanimation instead of xml. I don't know if it is good practice or recomended. But it seems more easy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this effect:

in your `OnBindViewHolder` of adapter:

```
private int lastAnimatedPosition = -1;

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
   {
     RunEnterAnimation(viewHolder.ItemView, position);   
   }
```

the `RunEnterAnimation` method:

```
private void RunEnterAnimation(View view, int position)
   {
      if (position > lastAnimatedPosition)
       {
          lastAnimatedPosition = position;
          ObjectAnimator animator1 = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(view, "TranslationY", -500, 0);
          animator1.SetDuration(2000);
          ObjectAnimator animator2 = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(view, "alpha", 0, 1);
          animator2.SetDuration(2000);
          AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
          animatorSet.PlayTogether(animator1, animator2);
          animatorSet.StartDelay=5;
          animatorSet.Start();
       }
   }
```

**ps**: if you dont want to use xml you could use the method above,and you alse could use `LayoutAnimation` with `Resources/anim/xx.xml` ,and also could implementation by `ItemAnimator`

Comment: The code works but it doesn't have the same behavious with item animator. Item animator it smooths very nice in each item. Object animator shows me all items at once.

Comment: yes，this method only run once when item create，so which one do you want

Comment: I need to create animation using object animator like this link below.https://www.journaldev.com/24088/android-recyclerview-layout-animations Using object animator instead item animator. If it is possible.

Comment: item animator is more focused on add and delete action,layout animation is focused on adapter animation,you could refer to this:https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators,but it also show all items at once  when item create like my sample above,it would smooths nice in each item when you scroll from second list